# Error while updating in the database

Tags: jdbc

Iam updating the database by executing the SQl queries through executeUpdate() method of PreparedStatement class.
How will i come to know if there was an error in the last update query??

Comment: ...will throw Exception. Wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You get an SQLException if something wents wrong.

In addition the executeUpdate() function returns the number of changed records in the database.